# Getting this error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error while uploading the CSV files in my website.
Screenshot attached below.

[image: Error screenshot]

I can see my data of csv file while debugging but it is stopping me to proceed further but i am not able to get this error, I have searched that on google to but they are not relevant to this.
I am using the library 
**https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js**

The code I am trying to upload file is below.

```js
    function file(event){
      var uploadFileEl = document.getElementById('upload');

      if(uploadFileEl.files.length > 0){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          fileProcess(reader.result.split(/\[\r\n\]+/));

        }  
        reader.readAsText(uploadFileEl.files\[0\]);
      }
    }

    function fileProcess(data) {
            var lines = data;
            //Set up the data arrays
            var time = \[\];
            var data1 = \[\];
            var data2 = \[\];
            var data3 = \[\];

            var headings = lines\[0\].split(','); // Splice up the first row to get the headings
          var headerCheckbox = document.getElementById('includeHeader');


          if(headerCheckbox.checked == true){


            for (var j=1; j<lines.length; j++) {
               var values = lines\[j\].split(','); // Split up the comma seperated values
               // We read the key,1st, 2nd and 3rd rows 
               time.push(values\[0\]); // Read in as string
               // Recommended to read in as float, since we'll be doing some operations on this later.
               if (values\[0\] =="" || values\[0\] == null  )
               {
                  delete values\[0\];
                  delete values\[1\]; 
                  delete values\[2\]; 
                  delete values\[3\];
               }
               else{
               data1.push(parseFloat(values\[1\])); 
               data2.push(parseFloat(values\[2\]));
               data3.push(parseFloat(values\[3\]));
                }
              }
```

The error I am getting is on this line

> fileProcess(reader.result.split(/[\r\n]+/));

What could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you are filling the call stack.

If you call a function that returns a function recursively and doesn't have a stop condition or it never fulfils it's stop condition that error will be throwed.

It appears that `fileProcess(reader.result.split(/[\r\n]+/))` it's being called recursively and it's filling the call stack.

Don't know exactly where, as I don't see any recursive calls in the code you posted, so I can't help you farer, but I hope this can shed light into your problem.

P.S: If you think there's some relevant extra code that you didn't post and edit your question leave me a comment and I'll update my answer aswell.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I can't locate where the recursive calls are made. In your code seems that there isn't any. But that's the reason you're getting the error. Hope that info helps you.

Comment: No problem friend :)